# Update keras python in the keras package in R

Tags: r, keras, rstudio

I am trying to do theses [examples](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/index.html)
 on the rstudio website but theses errors and warnings kept happening.

```
model = keras_model_sequential()

Keras loaded from keras Python module v0.3.2, however version 2.0.0 is 
required. Please update the keras Python package.
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to 
execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default 
to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove 
this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

inputs <- layer_input(shape = c(784))

Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'Input'
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you install or update Keras module on python with pip or conda?

Comment: Yes I have reinstall keras with conda.

Comment: I add to update the keras package and not just reinstall it.

Comment: Python does not work like R. I think It install the older version by default. You have to make a requirement for a newer version explicitly. One thing to keep in mind then. Glad you found your solution.